# Private tutoring middle school and high school students: most common requests

Tags: project, javascript, html, robotics

I'm a former professional programmer and I switched to private tutoring of math and CS about five years ago. For the past two years I've mainly tutored competitive programming to high school students. I'm getting burned out on it - I think I love regular projects more than competitions - so I'm looking to move into teaching languages and projects to middle/high school students.

I'm good at teaching Python to beginners and I have experience with making dynamic web pages with JavaScript.

I'm not experienced with creating apps for IOS or Android, and I've done no robot coding.

I'm wondering how often students want to create an app or do robot coding as their first project. And if there are any other common topics/projects that students (middle school/high school) request.

This kind of tutoring is mainly aimed at students who are not getting a CS curriculum in their schools; either they're too young for it to have started or they want to cover areas not covered by their schools.

Also, whether students are more often determined in what projects they want to do, or whether they are flexible. I imagine that web pages with JavaScript are cool enough to appeal to almost any student.

Comment: I just wanted to comment that you seem to have a lot of separate questions here, and all are highly context dependent. I think you might have a higher chance of getting a good response if you rephrase this to focus on a specific aspect, provide more detail on where you're based, and share the research you've done so far.